# Accepting client certificates from any CA

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6

I am setting up support for users to sign in with client certificates. Unfortunately IIS refuses to acknowledge any certificate not chained to an installed CA ([see this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257587)).

As the feature is implemented only for users´ convenience, it would be great to allow any client certificate. Is there any way to accomplish this?

My server is running Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6, but the behaviour is no different on my IIS 7 running locally. If IIS 7 could be customized to support any client certificate, I would be able to change though (given no solution for IIS 6 is available).

Comment: Just to clarify, you really cannot accept *any* client cert under SSL proper, because client cert exchange is part of SSL handshake (and you can't/shouldn't change that for any web server).

Comment: AFAIK browsers will allow the user to pick any certificate if no list of acceptable CAs is sent in the handshake. In Apache this is specified with the SSLNoCAList property, so it is technically possible. The question is whether it is possible using IIS.

Comment: AFAIK, SSLNoCAList doesn't do accomplish what your question asks.   Saying that the browser will select any cert, is *not* the same as saying the server will accept any client cert which doesn't chain to an installed root.  Please clarify which of the 3 notions of "any" you are really asking about.

Comment: 1). Server accepts *any* cert whatsoever (including self-signed certs or the equivalent, but then you must ask, "why bother").  2). you want the equivalent of Apache's SSLNoCAList, or 3). you want to be able to have IIS accept client certs which chain up to *any* set of root CA's of your choosing.

Comment: Can you explain why you have a "sign in" process if you don't care who is signing in?

Comment: erickson, say StackOverflow was to allow us to sign in by a client certificate. The issue of which certificate is the best fit is for each user to decide, not the site in general. I want to use certificates as a convenient way for users to authenticate to their own account - not to identify.

Comment: hi, have you found an appropriate solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think the normal way is for you to issue the certificates to them, and then for you to set up IIS to accept your cert as a root.

Comment: This is what many sites are doing, but I don't think it should be necessary (it might be possible it is).

Answer (score 1):

Implement this class:

```
    public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
    {
        public TrustAllCertificatePolicy() {}

        public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate cert,WebRequest req, int problem)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Set it using the following line of code.  Afterward any certificates, whether expired, name mismatch, etc. will be accepted.

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
```

Comment: The main issue is that IIS send a list of known CAs in the SSL handshake. This code doesn't change that. I need some way to override the IIS behaviour or configure it to send a wild card.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a new *root* CA cert via the `certmgr` command

```
certmgr --add -c -m Trust <CA_cert_DER_fmt>
```

Note: Unlike UNIXes, Windows manages certs for all applications *simultaneously*, which can have security implications, so beware of that

Comment: With regard to my response to your comment and the possible security implications, I don't think this is a valid answer.

Comment: Actually our comments above have nothing to do with the security implications I'm referring to in the Note.  There I'm simply warning that if you trust a new root CA for IIS, then by default your local IE will also trust that CA for outbound traffic to say https://yourbank.com, not always good.

Comment: While I do want to accept any certificate (by customizing the handshake), I have no intention of letting the server decide which to trust. This is a matter of my own and I will evaluate the certificates in my software.

Answer (score 0):

WCF allows you to write a [custom X.509 certificate handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354512.aspx). In the code you can do some check like comparing the thumbprint against know value in the database.